# How to pass facebook login response from javascript to php page?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, api

I am trying to add loing with facebook feature to my website, I used javascript to connect to facebook API, As you know facebook sends object named "response", I want to pass this object to my index.php page to read its content their.

could you please tell me how to pass and read this opject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can done with it by using `jQuery.ajax()` or `jQuery.post()` function. but it is not secured. Because js is open for all browser. Bad guys can send unexpected data and take chances to harm your app / web. Anyway it is your choice.

You can add a function here i have used `replace_login()` in `FB.getLoginStatus()` as following:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // connected
    replace_login();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // not_authorized
        } else {
            // not_logged_in
        }
    });
```

Now write `replace_login()` in same file and after `FB.getLoginStatus()` as below:

```
function replace_login(){
       FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          $.post("http://yourdomain.com/ajax_post_login",{ username: response.username, name: response.name, fb_res: response }, function(data) {
              alert(data);
          })
       });
  }
```

Check [facebook server-side-login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/), it will help you more.

Comment: thank you i do know that is not secure to depend only on client side scripts ...,

Answer (score 1):

If you need to work with facebook from your server, you can't use just js auth.

You need to implement "server login", described at [Login for Server-side Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/)

You need not implement all that complicated things, just find any library from internet, FB have its own library for php as I know, and use it to make server login. You can find many examples how to do it.